# What is wrong with my web.config? I cannot figure out how to call it

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm testing with this url:
http://localhost:55331/wcfDateTest.DateTimeService.svc/ProcessDateTime

But get this error:
404 Not Found

If I remove the  section, then this url works:
http://localhost:55331/DateTimeService.svc/ProcessDateTime

But I should be able to define the service right?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
  </system.web>
  
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="wcfDateTest.DateTimeService">
        <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="wcfDateTest.IDateTimeService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your configuration file, you are using the **WCF Server Application**. Its config file requires you to use the **WCF Test client** to open and view it.

**wcfDateTest** should be the name of your project. But in reality, the address of this endpoint will only be based on the name of the svc file in your project.
For example, in this project, the name of your svc file should be **DateTimeService.svc**

I'll give you an example of an initial project:

[image]

The file name is **Service1.svc**

The configuration file after opening in the wcf test client looks like this:
[image]

There are two ways to right-click on the config file to modify the address of the endpoint, but I tried it but it didn't work.

[image]

My advice to you is that you write WCF with an empty project.

Create three class files, one for the interface, one for the service, and one for the host.

Finally, the **app.config** file is completed with the W**CF Service Configuration Editor**. Here you can find the endpoint to modify the address.

Comment: Hi @Anders   Are there any updates on this issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.